# Local images are not appearing in kmz

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, kmz

I have information bubble in kml, which shows image along with some data.

That image is a local image which comes from respective folders. I have added a "file" addition before image src path , now i am able to see images on placemark in kml file.

But when I convert this kml file to kmz those images on bubbles are not appearing.

Can any one help me regarding this??

Cheers
Praveen.

Comment: Can you provide a sample KMZ file that exhibits the issue?  Are the image paths relative (with the images embedded in the KMZ) or absolute (with the images at that absolute path)?

Comment: without seeing the kml/kmz it is pretty near impossible to say.

Comment: @geocodezip the img src is local reference it is like              <img  src='file:///D:\Logo.jpg' />

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example KMZ file with an image in the infowindow](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/internalimage_testB_kmz.kmz), which works using KmlLayer in the Google Maps API v3 (can't seem to embed the link, so it is below):

[KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/internalimage_testB_kmz.kmz)

[geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/internalimage_testB_kmz.kmz)

[image]

<strike>and using [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Finternalimage_testB_kmz.kmz&hl=en&ll=45.000207,45&spn=0.001055,0.001725&sll=45.000268,45.000032&sspn=0.001055,0.001725&t=m&z=19&iwloc=lyrftr:kml:cjy5Wd1IV6vbsEDb7g4q2-_xmHHVRyKG8ivK_QQ,g89890df64c9bf213,,)</strike> (no longer supported)

The image is embedded in the KMZ.

The [KMZ documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives#externalrefs) states:

> They can refer to files within the same KMZ file, or to files contained in other KMZ files or stored elsewhere on the web.

Your File:/// reference is not "on the web".

It also states:

> However, if you use absolute references to local files, the links will break when the files are moved to a new system. Relative references avoid this problem.

Comment: <text><![CDATA[
 <table width=110% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
  <tr><td><img  width =100% src='file:///D:\STMAPPER\SM Mapper FEB 20_NMOD\SM customisation FEB 21 test\images\Logo.jpg' /></table></text> I have used file inclusion in src. This is working in kml but when i convert that kml to kmz then that image is not coming on the ballon

Comment: You may want to embed the image in the KMZ, see if that works.

Comment: @geicodezip if we use relative reference then the images will not appear on bubble

Comment: Do you have an KMZ file that exhibits the issue?